# Difference between a vector and an array processor

Tags: processor, vector-processing

Can someone please explain the difference between a vector and an array processor, which one encounters when learning about the computer architecture involved in parallel programming?

[One of the source](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/9907/vector-processor)  which I referred tells that the vector processor is also called an array processor. It's a bit confusing. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See "Supercomputer Languages" by R H Perrott and A Zarea-Aliabadi, ACM Computing Surveys, Vol 18, No 1, March 1986, pp. 7-8.
Some consider vector processors as SIMD computers and some don't.  If vector processors are SIMD computers, they are pipelined SIMD, whereas array processors are simultaneous SIMD.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *Can someone…explain the difference between a vector and an array processor…?*

Yes. There is **none**.

Arrays are but human abstractions. Common computers ***"see"*** vectors ( weakly organised  sections of their physical address-space, considered as a contiguous "block"-space, where vector's cell-by-cell data reside and get stored into and fetched from ( **this** is expensive, as of 2020/Q1 some CPUs may enjoy a few SIMD-instructions' tricks to move at once data to/from memory in their hardware-SIMD-specific blocks ( vectors of a few data-cells, currently not more than AVX-512 512bit-blocks, so eight `float64`-s or sixteen `float32`-s, etc. at max ) ) ).

So the data-*"representation"* is code-based, not hardware-based. Arrays, tensors in a bit more generalised view, are being stored in linearly addressed memory just by convention - being either:

- a **`F`**-ortran convention (row first, <sub>having the first index changing fastest</sub> ), or
- a **`C`**-language convention (column first, <sub>having the last index changing fastest</sub> )

so all such one-after-another aligned vector-splices, as a weakly, code-controlled sequences of vectors ( each vector being but a weakly code-controlled contiguous linear sequence of data-cells in a directly addressable memory )

> ( not speaking here knowingly about **sparse-**{vector|array|tensor}**-representation formats,** where non-zero elements' addressing conventions ( for the sake of memory-saving ( at a cost of losses in speed of access and cache-lines' inefficiencies ) due to the nature of sparsity often using indirect addressing tricks )  may go pretty wild to touch 'em here in brief )

---

### Known Exceptions :

If needed, SoC and FPGA devices may get designed so as to go an extra mile for indeed a hardware-supported {matrix|tensor}-processing, yet all **that comes at extra costs** - human invention + clever and energy-efficient silicon-level designs for such processors' matrix-*uops* having also extremely increased data-I/O on-die + off-die bandwidths, that are needed for a reasonably both large ( **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** sizes) and fast matrix-processing are rather very expensive, so do not expect any great magic from even these ultimately niche use-case approaches, where rather very limited, almost ASIC-alike product market sizes restrict such increased costs adjustments ( consumer electronics markets are not seeking for these, while MIL/R&D/FinTech/other special segments can pay for such extreme, non-COTS solutions ).